# Objects of superclass into arraylist?

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I have a problem that I can't understand or solve! I have just learned about inheritance and abstract methods. So I have done a superclass that I call Account and then two subclasses that I call savingsAccount and creditAccount. I have also put the objects of the subclasses into two separate arraylist.

But now I have to change it, because my teacher want me to create an account object and put that into an arraylist and reach the savingsAccount objects and the creditAccount objects from that list instead of having two separate list.

But when I'm reading about absract classes and methods, it seems that you can't create an object of an abstract superclass!? So how should I create an object of account and still use the abstract methods? Help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inheritance is used to define a `is-a` relationship. A SavingsAccount *is* an Account, and a CreditAccount *is* an Account. So, since a `List<Account>` is used to contain `Account`s, and a CreditAccount or SavingsAccount *is* an Account, you can add instances of both classes into the `List<Account>`:

```
Account a = new CreditAccount();
list.add(a);
```

When you'll get an account from the list (`Account a = list.get(0)` for example), this account will be either a CreditAccount or a SavingsAccount, and calling an abstract method will call the implementation of the method defined in the subclass.

Comment: +1. I was going to post an answer since the other two did not go into detail, but this covers the ground nicely.

Comment: +1 I voted for it even though I have a competing answer. Nice work.

Comment: Nice! But how would I handle several customer? Customers can have several different accounts. And I'm also wondering how do I get ans set values to the methods in the subclasses?

Comment: Then each instance of Customer should probably have its own list of accounts.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();
```

Will work even if `Account` is abstract.

Comment: Thanks! I get an error like cannot find symbol when I run this: List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();

Comment: Make sure you have imports for java.util.List and java.util.ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<Account> ();
```

it will work - **you can add both of your subclasses here**, but can't add Account object - as they are absract and cannot be created

Comment: Thanks! Hmm, a little bit hard to understand this! So I'm not creating an object of Account?! But how do I pass and reach methods of SavingsAccount and CreditAccounts inside the list?

Comment: Each of your specific accounts (subclasses) are `Account class` aswell. IF you need to check if `Account a` is type of `SavingsAccount` or `CreditAccounts` use `if (a incatanceof CreditAccounts) {} else {}`